# How to make searchview widget as autocomplete for google maps

Tags: android, autocomplete, searchview

I am new to android and developing an application which shows nearby places. It also have search functionality and searching is working properly. The problem is how to make searchView widget in action bar as autocomplete.

More precisely:

The problem is that this code autocompletes user text entry with suggestions in the searchview widget by getting data from google places api. On item selection of a suggested place, the selection does not get displayed in the searchview.

For example, if a person types "Berl" in the searchview, the autocomplete displays Berlin as a suggestion. But when the user selects Berlin from the list, the searchview box still displays Berl and not Berlin, Germany as it is in the suggestion list. I want to take the string that the user selects and display it in the search box

---

**Here is my Main Activity:**

```
GoogleMap mGoogleMap;


private Marker[] placeMarkers;
private final int MAX_PLACES = 20;
private MarkerOptions[] places;
private LocationManager locMan;
private int userIcon, foodIcon, otherIcon;

private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
private Marker userMarker;

Button pt;

//GPSTracker gps;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar ac=getSupportActionBar();
    ac.show();
    ac.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    ac.setTitle("Near By Mosque");
    ac.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

    userIcon = R.drawable.marker_img;
    foodIcon = R.drawable.nearby_ic;

    if(mGoogleMap==null){
        //map not instantiated yet


    SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();
    }
    if(mGoogleMap != null){
        //ok - proceed
    }
 handleIntent(getIntent());
 mGoogleMap.setMapType(mGoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
 mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
 placeMarkers = new Marker[MAX_PLACES];
 updatePlaces();
}




private void handleIntent(Intent intent){
    if(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction()))
    {
    String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
    doSearch(query);
    }
    else if(Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction()))
    {
    getPlace(intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.EXTRA_DATA_KEY));
    }
}

  @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void doSearch(String query){
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("query", query);
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, data, this);
    }

    private void getPlace(String query){
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("query", query);
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, data, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        //searchView.setSearchableInfo(PlaceProvider.DETAILS_URI);
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

        AutoCompleteTextView searchTextView =
                (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.abs__search_src_text);
        if (searchTextView != null) {
            searchTextView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                                        | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);            
            searchTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
        }
         searchView.getClass();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem query) {
        switch(query.getItemId()){
        case R.id.abs__list_item:
            Log.i("menuitme", query.toString());
            onSearchRequested();

            break;
        }
       return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, query);
 }



    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle query) {
        CursorLoader cLoader = null;
        if(arg0==0)
            cLoader = new CursorLoader(getBaseContext(), PlaceProvider.SEARCH_URI, null, null, new String[]{ query.getString("query") }, null);

        else if(arg0==1)
            cLoader = new CursorLoader(getBaseContext(), PlaceProvider.DETAILS_URI, null, null, new String[]{ query.getString("query") }, null);
        Log.i("new loader", cLoader.toString()); 
        return cLoader;

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor c) {
        showLocations(c);
        Log.i("cursor", c.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private void showLocations(Cursor c){
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = null;
        LatLng position = null;
        //mGoogleMap.clear();
        while(c.moveToNext()){
            markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            position = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(c.getString(1)),Double.parseDouble(c.getString(2)));
            markerOptions.position(position);
            markerOptions.title(c.getString(0));
            mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
        if(position!=null){
            CameraUpdate cameraPosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position);
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(cameraPosition);
        }
    }


private void updatePlaces(){
    //update location
    locMan = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location lastLoc = null;

    lastLoc=locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


    double lat = lastLoc.getLatitude();
    double lng = lastLoc.getLongitude();
    LatLng lastLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    Log.i("latlng",lastLatLng.toString());




    if(userMarker!=null) userMarker.remove();

    userMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(lastLatLng)
    .title("You are here")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(userIcon))
    .snippet("Your last recorded location"));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lastLoc.getLatitude(), lastLoc.getLongitude()), 15.0f));






    String types = "mosque";
    try {
    types = URLEncoder.encode(types, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    String placesSearchStr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/" +
    "json?location="+lat+","+lng+
    "&radius=3000&sensor=true" +
    "&types=" + types +
    "&key=AIzaSyCJv8kyIgi7hStqFN3qR-DXF6YMuQ2M6Y0";
    new GetPlaces().execute(placesSearchStr);


    }



private class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);


    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        Dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        Dialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... placesURL) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StringBuilder placesBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        //process search parameter string(s)
        for (String placeSearchURL : placesURL) {
        //execute search

            HttpClient placesClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            try {
                //try to fetch the data
                HttpGet placesGet = new HttpGet(placeSearchURL);
                HttpResponse placesResponse = placesClient.execute(placesGet);
                StatusLine placeSearchStatus = placesResponse.getStatusLine();

                if (placeSearchStatus.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                    //we have an OK response

                    HttpEntity placesEntity = placesResponse.getEntity();
                    InputStream placesContent = placesEntity.getContent();
                    InputStreamReader placesInput = new InputStreamReader(placesContent);
                    BufferedReader placesReader = new BufferedReader(placesInput);
                    String lineIn;
                    while ((lineIn = placesReader.readLine()) != null) {


                        placesBuilder.append(lineIn);
                        Log.i("line", lineIn);
                    }

                    }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                 placesClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            }

        }
        Log.i("post", placesBuilder.toString());
        return placesBuilder.toString();
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //parse place data returned from Google Places

        try
        {
           if(Dialog.isShowing())
            {
                 Dialog.dismiss();
            }
                    // do your Display and data setting operation here
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

        if(placeMarkers != null){
            for(int pm=0; pm<placeMarkers.length; pm++){
                if(placeMarkers[pm]!=null)
                    placeMarkers[pm].remove();

            }

            try {
                //parse JSON
                JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray placesArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("results");

                places = new MarkerOptions[placesArray.length()];
                //loop through places
                for (int p=0; p<placesArray.length(); p++) {
                    //parse each place
                    boolean missingValue=false;
                    LatLng placeLL=null;
                    String placeName="";
                    String vicinity="";

                    Log.i("place array", places.toString());
                    int currIcon = otherIcon;

                    try{
                        //attempt to retrieve place data values
                        missingValue=false;
                        JSONObject placeObject = placesArray.getJSONObject(p);
                        JSONObject loc = placeObject.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");
                        placeLL = new LatLng(
                                Double.valueOf(loc.getString("lat")),
                                Double.valueOf(loc.getString("lng")));
                        JSONArray types = placeObject.getJSONArray("types");

                        for(int t=0; t<types.length(); t++){
                            //what type is it
                            String thisType=types.get(t).toString();

                            vicinity = placeObject.getString("vicinity");
                            placeName = placeObject.getString("name");
                            Log.i("placename",placeName);
                            Log.i("types", types.toString());
                            if(thisType.contains("mosque")){
                                currIcon = foodIcon;
                                break;
                            }


                        }

                    }
                    catch(JSONException jse){
                        missingValue=true;
                        jse.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.i("marker", places.toString());
                    if(missingValue)    places[p]=null;
                    else
                        places[p]=new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(placeLL)
                        .title(placeName)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(currIcon))
                        .snippet(vicinity);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            if(places!=null && placeMarkers!=null){
                for(int p=0; p<places.length && p<placeMarkers.length; p++){
                    //will be null if a value was missing
                    if(places[p]!=null)
                        placeMarkers[p]=mGoogleMap.addMarker(places[p]);
                }
            }
        }

    }

}



@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    updatePlaces();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("MyMapActivity", "status changed");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("MyMapActivity", "provider enabled");
}


@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("MyMapActivity", "provider disabled");
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(mGoogleMap!=null){

    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mGoogleMap!=null){
        locMan.removeUpdates(this);
    }
}



}
```

Comment: lot of code not related to the problem. Please post only code relevant for the problem. Explain what you have tried and where you are blocked.

Comment: The problem is that this code autocompletes user text entry with suggestions in the searchview widget by getting data from google places api. On item selection of a suggested place, the selection does not get displayed in the searchview. For example, if a person types "Berl" in the searchview, the autocomplete displays Berlin as a suggestion. But when the user selects Berlin from the list, the searchview box still displays Berl and not Berlin, Germany as it is in the suggestion list. I want to take the string that the user selects and display it in the search box

Comment: @user3588131 can u share your autocomplete code